# Linux oathtool-generated TOTP 6-digit code invalid for 2FA SSH login using pam_oath.so

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security, authentication

I'm trying to set up TOTP 2FA login into an SSH session on my Ubuntu box.

To this end I have in /etc/users.oath:

```
HOTP/T30/6 testuser – 8436e373cbdabce46a5d8d019c463a
```

(I'm generating this value over and over so safe to post here and testing system is air-gapped.)

/etc/users.oath is 0x600 permitted and owned by root:

```
# ls /etc/users.oath -l
-rw------- 1 root root 55 Jan 29 15:39 /etc/users.oath
#
```

In /etc/pam.d/sshd I have as the last line

```
auth required pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=30 digits=6
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config has

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

and user "testuser" exists and has a password, added via adduser & passwd.

I generate the base32 secret like this:

```
#oathtool --verbose --totp 8436e373cbdabce46a5d8d019c463a
Hex secret: 8436e373cbdabce46a5d8d019c463a
Base32 secret: QQ3OG46L3K6OI2S5RUAZYRR2
Digits: 6
Window size: 0
Step size (seconds): 30
Start time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (0)
Current time: 2024-01-29 13:51:57 UTC (1706536317)
Counter: 0x363FD3F (56884543)

261816
#
```

Then I get the 6 digit TOTP for a 2FA login attempt via

```
oathtool --base32 --totp QQ3OG46L3K6OI2S5RUAZYRR2 -d 6
```

and quickly type it into my SSH client in the 2FA login attempt.

However, the 6 digit TOTP code given by oathtool itself for the base32 secret is always invalid when then trying to SSH into the box using the user "testuser":

```
Using username "testuser".
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password:
| One-time password (OATH) for `testuser':
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password:
| One-time password (OATH) for `testuser':
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
```

/var/log/auth.log just shows

```
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=172.1.2.3  user=testuser
error: PAM: Authentication failure for testuser from 172.1.2.3
```

repeatedly.

I have the Ubuntu "libpam-oath" package installed, and the necessary .so file exists in /lib/security:

```
# ls /lib/security/pam_oath.so -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18488 Feb  9  2019 /lib/security/pam_oath.so
#
```

What am I doing wrong that the base32 secret calculated by oathtool, if converted to its time-based 6 digit code, is invalid for pam_oath.so via the SSHD server running on the same machine when attempting a 2FA-based login?

(I'm deliberately testing on the same machine and not using a mobile / cellphone with Google Authenticator or Authy or similar, to avoid any time-related TOTP issues.)

How can I get 2FA based TOTP working in Ubuntu 20.04?

It seems oathtool and PAM's pam_oath.so module are incompatible.

Comment: What version of OpenSSH are you running?

Comment: Does your system log actually show **pam_oath** rejecting the OTP? All I see so far is **pam_unix** reporting failure for the regular password?

Comment: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11, OpenSSL 1.1.1f

Comment: No, even at 'LogLevel DEBUG3' for the SSHD daemon I do not see that the OTP is rejected. It appears it is accepting the password, since if I type in an incorrect password, I never get the prompt for the one-time password at all, it just asks for the password again...

Comment: There are no /var/log/auth.log entries specifically saying the OTP has been rejected, only what I posted above. I gather something is wrong lower down in the chain, since I see no messages at all from pam_oath in the SSHD log?

Comment: I managed to do what I needed using the information at this link:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview

E.g. link a Google Authenticator TOTP to an SSH user / SFTP account.